# Verilog simulator for windows

Tags: verilog, simulation, hardware, simulator

I'm looking for a verilog simulator for windows. All I see is the source code for veriwell, with makefiles for Linux. Anybody have any suggestion on where I can find the binaries for veriwell or other Verilog simulator.

Comment: Does it need to be open source?  I personally haven't used it, but I've heard icarus verilog is pretty good.  I personally use modelsim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veriwell is an excellent simulator, but unfortunately only supports vlog-95, which makes it unusable for realistic designs. Icarus is the way to go - I'm pretty sure you can download Windows binaries, very reliable and stable, active support, good language compliance, very low level of bugs (much better than at least one widely-used commercial simulator, for example).